# Dynamically Loading Images not cached

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load an animated image on top of an element, and to do this I am switching between a list of pngs (labelled 1 - 124) and creating an image element for each of them and giving them a src.

The idea is I can have an empty image element and run a function to swap the src every 25 milliseconds with the next image in the list to give an animated image effect.

This works fine on Mac (chrome) as it loads the images ONCE and then seemlesly changes the src without loading any more images (I checked this by looking in the network tab of the chrome dev tools).

But for some reason on my windows PC it is sluggish and is trying to load the image from the server again every 25 miliseconds ..

```
cycle_images: function() {
    this.imageCount = (this.imageCount < 123) ? this.imageCount + 1 : 0;
    document.querySelector('.animated_image').html = this.imageList[this.imageCount];
},
```

This is the code I am using and I am confused why it works fine on my macbook but not my pc. Is there any way to force images to not re-load and just looad from cache?

Comment: well I am sure it is taking longer than 25 milliseconds to fetch an image from the server and load it. Are you actually preloading them to start? (seems weird you are just reinventing a gif ;)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be creating 124 `img` and make them invisible on the page and then change your image accordingly.

But a most promissing and proper way could be concatenating these image into one `gif` file and load it once! This way use internal engine to render and it is much more effecient and also does not affect on user experience.